# Rust - создание функции с возвращением класса MappedRows из библиотеки rusqlite

Tags: rust

У меня есть некоторый код

```
struct DB {
    db : Connection
}

impl DB {
    // constructor
    fn new(file : &str) -> DB {
        let mut d = Connection::open(file).unwrap();
        d.execute("create table if not exists u (i unsigned integer)", NO_PARAMS).unwrap();
        DB {db : d}
    }

    // returns length of values
    fn len(&self) -> u32 {
        self.db.query_row("select count(i) from u", NO_PARAMS, |r| r.get(0)).unwrap()
    }

    fn print(&self) {
        if self.len() > 0 {
            let mut t = self.db.prepare("select i from u").unwrap();
            for i in t.query_map(NO_PARAMS, |r| -> u32 { r.get(0) } ).unwrap() {
                println!("id {}", i.unwrap());
            }
        } else {
            println!("Nothing");
        }
    }
}
```

Можно ли мне как то упростить вот как будет выглядеть на следующем коде

```
struct DB {
    db : Connection
}

impl DB {
    // constructor
    fn new(file : &str) -> DB {
        let mut d = Connection::open(file).unwrap();
        d.execute("create table if not exists u (i unsigned integer)", NO_PARAMS).unwrap();
        DB {db : d}
    }

    // returns length of values
    fn len(&self) -> u32 {
        self.db.query_row("select count(i) from u", NO_PARAMS, |r| r.get(0)).unwrap()
    }

    fn iter(&self) -> MappedRows {
        self.db.prepare("select i from u").unwrap().query_map(NO_PARAMS, |r| -> u32 {r.get(0)} ).unwrap();
    }

    fn print(&self) {
        if self.len() > 0 {
            for i in self.iter() {
                println!("id {}", i.unwrap());
            }
        } else {
            println!("Nothing");
        }
    }
}
```

Но у меня идёт ошибка на месте MappedRows. Ему нехватает некий F, но как я покопался это лямбда функция или просто параметр принимающий функцию. Если упростить не получится до второго кода то ладно, а так желательно бы хотелось чтобы ещё получать как нибудь потом из базы элементы. Сразу скажу что база данных хранит только кучку чисел без id и всего этого

Данные ошибки

wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
expected 1 type argumentrustc(E0107)
main.rs(52, 27): expected 1 type argument
pub struct MappedRows<'stmt, F>
An iterator over the mapped resulting rows of a query.

Мне предложили также другой вариант, но у меня получился только ещё больше ошибок

```
    fn iter<T, F>(&self) -> MappedRows<F> 
    where F: FnMut(&Row<'_, '_>) -> T
    {
        let t = self.db.prepare("select i from u").unwrap();
        t.query_map(NO_PARAMS, |r| -> u32 {r.get(0)} ).unwrap()
    }
```

mismatched types

expected type parameter, found closure

note: expected type `rusqlite::MappedRows<'_, F>`
         found type `rusqlite::MappedRows<'_, [closure@src/main.rs:56:36: 56:57]>`rustc(E0308)
main.rs(56, 13): expected type parameter, found closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создал для вас пример, как можно сделать: https://github.com/LooMaclin/return_mapped_rows_iter_example_rusqlite/blob/master/src/main.rs#L24-L34

Вкратце, необходимая сигнатура для `iter`:

```rust
    fn iter<'a, 'stmt: 'a>(&'a self, stmt: &'a mut Statement<'stmt>) -> impl Iterator<Item = rusqlite::Result<u32>> + 'a  {
        let query_map = stmt.query_map(NO_PARAMS, |r| -> u32 {r.get(0)});
        let query_map_unwrapped = query_map.unwrap();
        query_map_unwrapped
    }

    fn print(&self) {
        if self.len() > 0 {
            let mut stmt= self.db.prepare("select i from u").unwrap();
            for i in self.iter(&mut stmt) {
                println!("id {}", i.unwrap());
            }
        } else {
            println!("Nothing");
        }
}
```

Увидев код, вы зададитесь вопросом - зачем было вынесено создание `Statement` за пределы функции `iter`. Для того, чтобы объяснить это, сделал небольшой пример: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bef45646e58f71410af61deb142564f5

```rust
struct A {
    a: String,
}

struct B<'a> {
    a: &'a str,
}

impl A {
    fn get_b(&self) -> B {
        B { a: &self.a }
    }
}

struct C;

impl C {
    fn create_a(&self) -> A {
        A {
            a: "abc".to_string(),
        }
    }

    fn iter(&self) -> &B {
        let a = self.create_a();
        &a.get_b()
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

В данном случае, в функции создавался `Statement`, который в её же скоупе и дропался. При этом возвращаемые данные (`MappedRows<'stmt>`) имели ссылку на `Statement`. 
Вот эта связь:

1) `MappedRows<'stmt>` хранит в себе `Rows<'stmt>`: https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.16.0/src/rusqlite/row.rs.html#69-72

2) `Rows<'stmt>` хранит в себе `Option<&'stmt Statement<'stmt>>`: https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.16.0/src/rusqlite/row.rs.html#8-10

Поэтому и появляется необходимость создавать `Statement`, с таким временем жизни, который больше скоупа этой функции (то есть принимать его извне, в аргументах).

Comment: Спасибо, теперь мне понятна вся суть проблемы. Там где ' стоит быть повнимательнее...